Slow response time and Internal Server Error when calling Flask API endpoint for music recommendation system
I'm new to Flaks Development. I have developed a music recommendation system integrated with the Spotify API using Flask for my final year project. The system retrieves personal playlists from Spotify via the Flask API and generates recommended playlists by combining this data with other datasets. However, when I call the recommendation API endpoint, I encounter two issues:

Slow response time: The endpoint takes too long to respond.
Internal Server Error (status 500): Sometimes, the request results in an internal server error.

Technologies used:

Python
Flask
Spotify API
numpy
pandas
scikit-learn (sklearn)
matplotlib

@app.route('/recommendation', methods=['GET'])
async def recommendation():
    try:
        import pdb;
        pdb.set_trace()
        spotify_df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
        data_w_genre = pd.read_csv('data_w_genres.csv')

        # Optimize string operations
        data_w_genre['genres_upd'] = data_w_genre['genres'].str.extract(r"'([^']*)'", expand=False).str.replace(' ',
                                                                                                                '_')
        spotify_df['artists_upd'] = spotify_df['artists'].str.extract(r"'([^']*)'|\"(.*?)\"", expand=False).fillna(
            '').sum(axis=1)

        # Use vectorized operations
        spotify_df['artists_song'] = spotify_df['artists_upd'] + spotify_df['name']
        spotify_df.sort_values(['artists_song', 'release_date'], ascending=False, inplace=True)
        spotify_df.drop_duplicates('artists_song', inplace=True)

        artists_exploded = spotify_df[['artists_upd', 'id']].explode('artists_upd')
        artists_exploded_enriched = artists_exploded.merge(data_w_genre, how='left', left_on='artists_upd',
                                                           right_on='artists')
        artists_exploded_enriched_nonnull = artists_exploded_enriched[~artists_exploded_enriched.genres_upd.isnull()]

        # Use pandas' groupby and apply with axis='columns' for faster performance
        artists_genres_consolidated = artists_exploded_enriched_nonnull.groupby('id')['genres_upd'].agg(
            list).reset_index()
        artists_genres_consolidated['consolidates_genre_lists'] = artists_genres_consolidated['genres_upd'].apply(
            lambda x: list(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x))))

        spotify_df = spotify_df.merge(artists_genres_consolidated[['id', 'consolidates_genre_lists']], on='id',
                                      how='left')

        # Use pandas' dt accessor for datetime operations
        spotify_df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(spotify_df['release_date']).dt.year

        float_cols = spotify_df.dtypes[spotify_df.dtypes == 'float64'].index.values
        ohe_cols = 'popularity'

        # Use vectorized operations instead of apply with lambda
        spotify_df['popularity_red'] = (spotify_df['popularity'] / 5).astype(int)

        # Use list comprehension instead of apply with lambda
        spotify_df['consolidates_genre_lists'] = spotify_df['consolidates_genre_lists'].apply(
            lambda d: d if isinstance(d, list) else [])

        complete_feature_set = await create_feature_set(spotify_df, float_cols=float_cols)

        tracks = {}
        list_photo = {}
        for i in sp.current_user_playlists()['items']:
            tracks[i['name']] = i['uri'].split(':')[2]
            list_photo[i['uri'].split(':')[2]] = i['images'][0]['url']

        playlist_random = await create_necessary_outputs(tracks['name'], tracks, spotify_df)

        complete_feature_set_playlist_vector_random, complete_feature_set_nonplaylist_random = await generate_playlist_feature(
            complete_feature_set, playlist_random, 1.09)
        random_top40 = await generate_playlist_recos(spotify_df, complete_feature_set_playlist_vector_random,
                                                     complete_feature_set_nonplaylist_random)

        return jsonify(random_top40)
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e), 500


async def ohe_prep(df, column, new_name):
    tf_df = pd.get_dummies(df[column])
    feature_names = tf_df.columns
    tf_df.columns = [new_name + "|" + str(i) for i in feature_names]
    tf_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    return tf_df


async def create_feature_set(df, float_cols):
    # tfidf genre lists
    tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
    tfidf_matrix = tfidf.fit_transform(df['consolidates_genre_lists'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x)))
    genre_df = pd.DataFrame(tfidf_matrix.toarray())
    genre_df.columns = ['genre' + "|" + i for i in tfidf.get_feature_names_out()]
    genre_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    # explicity_ohe = ohe_prep(df, 'explicit','exp')
    year_ohe = await ohe_prep(df, 'year', 'year') * 0.5
    popularity_ohe = await ohe_prep(df, 'popularity_red', 'pop') * 0.15

    # scale float columns
    floats = df[float_cols].reset_index(drop=True)
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    floats_scaled = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(floats), columns=floats.columns) * 0.2

    # concanenate all features
    final = pd.concat([genre_df, floats_scaled, popularity_ohe, year_ohe], axis=1)

    # add song id
    final['id'] = df['id'].values

    return final


async def create_necessary_outputs(playlist_name, id_dic, df):
    # Use Spotify API to retrieve playlist tracks
    playlist_tracks = pd.DataFrame(await sp.playlist(id_dic[playlist_name])['tracks']['items'])

    # Extract relevant columns and rename them
    playlist_df = playlist_tracks[
        ['track.artists[0].name', 'track.name', 'track.id', 'track.album.images[1].url', 'added_at']]
    playlist_df.columns = ['artist', 'name', 'id', 'url', 'date_added']

    # Convert date_added to datetime
    playlist_df['date_added'] = pd.to_datetime(playlist_df['date_added'])

    # Filter playlist_df to include only tracks present in df
    playlist_df = playlist_df[playlist_df['id'].isin(df['id'].values)].sort_values('date_added', ascending=False)

    return playlist_df


async def generate_playlist_feature(complete_feature_set, playlist_df, weight_factor):
    complete_feature_set_playlist = complete_feature_set[
        complete_feature_set['id'].isin(playlist_df['id'].values)]  # .drop('id', axis = 1).mean(axis =0)
    complete_feature_set_playlist = complete_feature_set_playlist.merge(playlist_df[['id', 'date_added']], on='id',
                                                                        how='inner')
    complete_feature_set_nonplaylist = complete_feature_set[
        ~complete_feature_set['id'].isin(playlist_df['id'].values)]  # .drop('id', axis = 1)

    playlist_feature_set = complete_feature_set_playlist.sort_values('date_added', ascending=False)

    most_recent_date = playlist_feature_set.iloc[0, -1]

    for ix, row in playlist_feature_set.iterrows():
        playlist_feature_set.loc[ix, 'months_from_recent'] = int(
            (most_recent_date.to_pydatetime() - row.iloc[-1].to_pydatetime()).days / 30)

    playlist_feature_set['weight'] = playlist_feature_set['months_from_recent'].apply(lambda x: weight_factor ** (-x))

    playlist_feature_set_weighted = playlist_feature_set.copy()
    # print(playlist_feature_set_weighted.iloc[:,:-4].columns)
    playlist_feature_set_weighted.update(
        playlist_feature_set_weighted.iloc[:, :-4].mul(playlist_feature_set_weighted.weight, 0))
    playlist_feature_set_weighted_final = playlist_feature_set_weighted.iloc[:, :-4]
    # playlist_feature_set_weighted_final['id'] = playlist_feature_set['id']
    return playlist_feature_set_weighted_final.sum(axis=0), complete_feature_set_nonplaylist


async def generate_playlist_recos(df, features, nonplaylist_features):
    non_playlist_df = df[df['id'].isin(nonplaylist_features['id'].values)]
    non_playlist_df['sim'] = await cosine_similarity(nonplaylist_features.drop('id', axis=1).values,
                                                     features.values.reshape(1, -1))[:, 0]
    non_playlist_df_top_40 = non_playlist_df.sort_values('sim', ascending=False).head(40)
    non_playlist_df_top_40['url'] = non_playlist_df_top_40['id'].apply(
        lambda x: sp.track(x)['album']['images'][1]['url'])

    return non_playlist_df_top_40


Steps to reproduce:

Make a request to the recommendation API endpoint.
Observe slow response time and potential internal server error.

Expected behavior:
I expect the recommendation API endpoint to respond in a reasonable amount of time and without errors.
Additional information:

Code snippets of relevant Flask endpoints, especially the recommendation endpoint.
Details about the datasets being used and how they are integrated.
Any specific error messages or traceback logs you receive.
Information about the server environment where Flask is deployed (e.g., hardware specifications, network configuration).
Any recent changes or updates made to the system that could potentially affect performance.
Any debugging steps you've already taken or potential avenues for investigation.
Thank you for your help!


The question is too broad. Please provide a minimal and reproducible example with clear intention. That way you will get a higher chance of receiving a response from others.
Slow response time is very ambigious. That could be your internet speed or any other problem. Narrowing it down is a step in being a developer.

Yes The main question is Recommendation API endpoint response time is too long and it just shows response status 500 without any error

Now, I have solved the error. It was because flask does not support async method and I change using Quart fraemwork
